# Redirected MP3 stream do not load in Webkit browsers - Flash 9

Tags: flash, redirect, webkit, stream, mp3

I'm busy creating a mp3 player (for a music store). Everything works perfectly. Some of the files will be redirected to the original source (located on other server) when Flash wants to load the stream. In all major browsers this works perfectly except Webkit browsers such as Chrome and Safari. I have tried to send a "Moved Permanently" 301 header as well as a normal redirect but does not work. Also when i try to download it from the address bar nothing happen (in other browsers i get a popup to download the stream).

Does anyone knows a solution to this? It is really a webkit only thing.

Thanks for leading me into the right direction.

Comment: Got it, 303 is the way to go. Topic closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, 303 is the way to go. Topic closed